# Calculate Sum of Positive and Sum of Negative changes

Tags: excel

In Excel I have the following column of values:

| Values | Change |
| --- | --- |
| 10 |  |
| 12 | 2 |
| 12 | 0 |
| 11 | -1 |
| 13 | 2 |
| 15 | 2 |
| 14 | -1 |
| 18 | 4 |

Is it possible, without VBA and without computing the column Change, the following:

```
SUM of Positive Changes = 2 + 2 + 2 + 4 = 10

SUM of Negative Changes = -1 + (-1) = -2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using SUMPRODUCT:

For positive:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A9-A2:A8)*((A3:A9-A2:A8)>0))
```

and similarly for negative, changing to `>0` to  `<0`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you could use FILTER.

For positive changes:

```
=SUM(FILTER(A3:A9-A2:A8,(A3:A9-A2:A8)>0))
```

For negative changes:

```
=SUM(FILTER(A3:A9-A2:A8,(A3:A9-A2:A8)<0))
```